# presence of bitcoin addresses on blockchain

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I recently read some where the speaker mentioned bitcoin doesn't store addresses in the block chain. If addresses do not exist on the blockchain, how can you check their balances on - for example - blockchain com?

Answer (score 1):

Payment addresses stored within transactions, and transactions stored within blockchain. Thus, speaker is not right - addresses stored in the blockchain, and by scanning the blockchain, you can fetch all activity for any address. Of course, balance - just result (sum) of all activities.

However, Bitcoin (or other bitcoin-like crypto) does not build it's own address index, and there is impossible quickly fetch balance or activity history for some specific address directly from a node. Explorers scans blockchain and build his own transaction history withing his own database. Of course, when new block comes in, explorer updates his own DB, and by this way - he maintains actual history for all accounts.